# Complicated Regex Validator

Tags: c#, regex, validation, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to use a regular expression validator. The trick is that it might require more logic but I was hoping I can accomplish this with just regex. So if the string to test ends with @faxmail.com then it also must start with "1,". Otherwise, essentially anything that doesn't end in @faxmail.com is a match. So if I did this with just C# it might look like

```
if(someString.EndsWith("@faxmail.com"))
{
    if(!someString.StartsWith("1,")) return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

I've tried something like `(?(?=^(\w+)@faxmail.com$)(^1)))` and it partly works. In the end I need something like:

```
1,test@faxmail.com (passes)
fail@faxmail.com (fails)
test@testmail.com (passes)
```

Is what I'm trying to accomplish possible with a regex or do I just need to punt and use C# logic?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this Regex:

```
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"^1.*(@faxmail.com)$|.*(?<!@faxmail.com)$");
```

There are two regexes to match here:

1. Starts with 1, followed by any characters, and ending with "@faxmail.com", or
2. Any string not ending with "@faxmail.com"

You can use below test cases to verify:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^1.*(@faxmail.com)$|.*(?<!@faxmail.com)$");
Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("1,test@faxmail.com")); //True
Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("fail@faxmail.com")); //False
Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("test@testmail.com")); //True
Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("faxmail@faxmail.com@testmail.com")); //True
Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("2,test@faxmail.com")); //False
```

Comment: Wow this works great! Thanks. Only thing is that the 2nd to last test case (faxmail@faxmai.com@testmail.com) realistically shouldn't pass because our fax server would probably choke. So I'll probably have to make some adjustments and keep testing. But this will put me in the right direction. Thanks again!

Comment: Yep, you might want to implement a standard email regex to catch that kind of email input before this one.

Comment: Yep. That actually was part of my plan using an EmailAddressAttribute as well as a derived RegexAttribute.

Comment: Only drawback is that Javascript apparently doesn't support look behind so this doesn't seem to work for the client side validation.